# unsigned char subtraction efficiency

Tags: c++, c

I have many files(about 50MB) which contains numbers between 0 and 255.

I Load them as unsigned char. What happens when I perform an subtraction between them? The results are always an integer(sizeof() gives 4) even when there are no overflows.

Comment: @Joachim: I think the question is the sentence with the question mark.

Answer (score 5):

Formally they're promoted to `int` (on a usual machine where `char` is less than `int`) and then the arithmetic operation is performed.

In practice a compiler may notice that the result is converted back to `char`, and therefore emit only byte-size machine code.

Regarding the efficiency, if it is important then **measure**.

Comment: The importance of measuring cannot be stressed enough, since the efficiency will depend on the machine.  Most machines can't do arithmetic on bytes (which is why the language specifies implicit promotion).  Whether reading a byte into a register costs extra or not will depend on the architecture.  And if it does, the compiler may be able to optimize the cost out (as you describe for Intel), or not.